# ChoiceField - choices based on boolean field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to have a choicefield that only displays the users with the ProjectManager boolean field checked as true.  I am having some trouble figuring out the way to do it though.

A little background.  When a user is created, there is a checkbox that they can select if they are a project manager or not.  If they check it, I want the dropdown choice field to display all the project managers (later, when creating a new project).

Here is my code snippets to help.

Project - Models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
client = models.ForeignKey(Clients, related_name='projects')
project_manager = models.ForeignKey(customUser, related_name='Project Manager')
created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='created_by')
...
```

Clients - models.py

```
class Clients(models.Model):

   client_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Client Name', unique=True)
   ...    

class customUser(User):
   company = models.ForeignKey(Clients, related_name="belongs to")
   pm = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Project Manager')
```

Project forms.py

```
class TimeMaterialsForm(ModelForm):
status = forms.ChoiceField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
project_manager = forms.ChoiceField(??)
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(TimeMaterialsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['status'].initial = 'T'
    self.fields.keyOrder = ['proj_name', 'client','project_manager','starts_on','desc', 'due_date','completed_on','quote_value','pt_percent','pt_desc','purchase_order','SRED','status', 'notes']
    self.fields['status'].widget=forms.HiddenInput()

...
```

Thanks everyone!

Steve

Comment: are you using just the admin or a custom interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

```
class TimeMaterialsForm(ModelForm):
   status = forms.ChoiceField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
   project_manager = forms.forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=customUser.objects.filter(pm=True))
   ...
```

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield

Comment: getting closer, I am now presented with this error message. Caught OperationalError while rendering: (1054, "Unknown column 'clients_customuser.pm' in 'field list'") and its pointing to my template when I call the {{form}}.

Comment: I am a bit unclear....you wan't the list of customUsers who have `pm` field `true` right?

Comment: I forgot to run syncdb and thats why I was getting that error, thanks for the help!

Comment: have you synced your databases?